# Clearing NSUserDefaults after specified time period iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2

I have created NSUserDefaults object, it will be updated with the new value whenever an even will occur. 
What I want is (as per my application requirement) that object should be cleared every 7 days. 
Like if 1st time that NSUserDefaults are updated today so exact after 7 days, a method should work and clear the NSUserDefaults. 
So that, new values would be assigned from then on for the next 7 days.

Is it possible in objective-c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is store an NSDate object. Then every time the application is launched (or more often) check if the time difference between then and now is 7 days.

```
const NSString *kFirstLaunchDateKey = @"firstLaunchDate";
NSDate *firstLaunchDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kFirstLaunchDateKey];

//  If this is the first time the app has been launched we record right now as the first time the app was launched.
if (!firstLaunchDate) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:kFirstLaunchDateKey];
    return;
}

NSTimeInterval *diff = abs([firstLaunchDate timeIntervalSinceNow]);
if (diff > 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) {
//      Seven days have passed since the app was first launched. 
//      Display the rate button.
}
```

If it is call

```
- (void)removePersistentDomainForName:(NSString *)domainName
```

With your application’s bundle identifier as the parameter.

[From Apple’s documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> `domainName`
>   The domain whose keys and values you want. This value should be equal to your application's bundle identifier.

Answer (score 4):

yes.. store the `NSDate`(current Date) as an object in `NSUserdefaults`.

At every launch of your app.. get the date from the defaults and compare it to current Date..

If the interval is more than 7 days(you will have to do math calculation to get the result)

then set the object as nil

using

```
[defaults setNilforKey: ];
```