# Clear NSUserDefaults at set time

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

How can I clear keys in NSUserDefaults at a given time? I have a local notification set up at 8p.m. and at that time I also want NSUserDefaults to be cleared. Other responses to similar questions have not fulfilled what I want — often they have code which is too complicated for my need.

I know how to clear NSUserDefaults on launch, but integrating this with a time interval or at a particular time is beyond me. Any code would be appreciated.

Comment: what code is too complicated for you? what was your approach (post some code). If you can do this at application launch, what is the problem doing it when you receive the notification?

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684900/clearing-nsuserdefaults-after-specified-time-period-iphone... I was thinking of using NSDateComponents to get a time (which I'm happy with) but unsure how to link that to clearing NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can clear everything in `NSUserDefaults` :

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

Comment: I asked specifically about doing it at a particular time, not clearing everything at app launch. As I said, I'm happy with that.