# Clean NSUserDefaults value in time

Tags: swift

Can I clean NSUserDefaults value in time? For example in 2 days?

I set it by:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue("yes", forKey: "isWinner")
```

Comment: There's nothing out of the box that I know of. You could save another `NSUserDefault` containing a `NSDate` object representing the time you set the key. Then, when using the app you could occasionally test against that date; When the difference is higher than 2 days, remove the keys.

Comment: @Padarom The way he has specified is the perfect one. Check out this link to know more on how to do that! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684900/clearing-nsuserdefaults-after-specified-time-period-iphone